# HTML to Excel Via JavaScript Export - Image Not Showing (any png from the web)

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export

I have an application which exports some html as excel (xls) file. Table and all the data works but images dont show.

How can i make excel to show these images from the urls?

Example contents of the file is here:

```
  <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
      <head> 
      <style>

  
  </style>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <xml><x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
  <x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>2022-11-14</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions>
  </x:ExcelWorksheet>
  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
  </x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <table id="table1" class="jss171" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 1px #000">
  <tbody><tr><td style="text-align:left;height:100px">
  <img style="width:200px" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-wordmark-en.svg"></td><td colspan="4"></td></tr></tbody><tbody>
  
  
  </tbody></table></body></html>
```

Comment: What are you using in javascript to convert or export html as xls files? Do you want the fix the export functionality (in js), or just add some macros to excel (in VBA) to show images?

Comment: You better make your question clear and answerable instead of throwing in a bounty.